# How to find the tallest height between each pair of two divs and apply that tallest height to both the divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say for example I have this following HTML:

```
<div class="TwoColumnUnit">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Left">
        <div class="newsLetterDiv">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="left_Side">
                    <i class="fas fas fa-route"></i>
                    <h3>This is about Tennis</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right_Side">
                    <p><span>Tennis is a racket sport that is played either individually against a single opponent or between two teams of two players each.&nbsp;</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsLetterDiv">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="left_Side">
                    <i class="fas fas fa-basketball"></i>
                    <h3>This is about Basketball</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right_Side">
                    <p><span>Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.Basketball is a team sport in which two teams, most commonly of five players each, opposing one another on a rectangular court, compete with the primary objective of shooting a basketball through the defender's hoop, while preventing the opposing team from shooting through their own hoop.</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 TwoColumnUnit_Right">    
        <div class="newsLetterDiv">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="left_Side">
                    <i class="fas fas fa-Football"></i>
                    <h3>This is about Football</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right_Side">
                    <p><span>Association football, more commonly known as football or soccer, is a team sport played between two teams of 11 players each, who primarily use their feet to propel a ball around a rectangular field called a pitch.</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsLetterDiv">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="left_Side">
                    <i class="fas fas fa-Swimming"></i>
                    <h3>This is about Swimming</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right_Side">
                    <p><span>Swimming is an individual or team racing sport that requires the use of one's entire body to move through water. </span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is picture of how the HTML look [image: picture].

I want to find the tallest height between `Tennis` and `Football`, and then set that tallest height, as the height for both `Tennis` and `Football`.

Likewise, I want to find the tallest height between `Basketball` and `Swimming`, and then set that tallest height as the height for both `Basketball` and `Swimming`.

I know how to find the max height using the `Math.max`. But how do find the tallest height between each pair of two divs?

What I tried:

```
('.TwoColumnUnit').each(function() {
  var pairs = [$(this).find('.TwoColumnUnit_Left'), $(this).find('.TwoColumnUnit_Right')];
  pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
      if (pair.length > 0) {
          var boxes = pair.find('.newsLetterDiv > div');
          var maxHeight = 0;
          boxes.each(function() {
              $(this).css('height', '');
              maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
          });
          boxes.css('height', maxHeight + 'px');
      }
  });
});
```

The problem with this code is that it's finding the tallest height between all 4 divs and then applying that tallest height value as height for all 4 of the items.

But how can I find the tallest height between the first left and right div, and then between the second left and right div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit verbose and I'm sure there is a better way than breaking it out like this but if I understand your question correctly, this is the long way of doing this compare:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {          
    var tennisHeight = $("#tennis").height()
    var basketballHeight = $("#basketball").height()
    var swimmingHeight = $("#swimming").height()
    var footballHeight = $("#football").height()
    var left = 0
    var right = 0

    if (tennisHeight > basketballHeight) {
        $("#basketball").height(tennisHeight)           
        left = tennisHeight
    }else {
        $("#tennis").height(basketballHeight)           
        left = basketballHeight
    }

    if (footballHeight > swimming) {
        $("#swimming").height(footballHeight)           
        right = footballHeight
    }else {
        $("#football").height(swimmingHeight)           
        right = swimmingHeight
    }

    var winner = Math.max(left, right)
    console.log(winner)

});
```

You then have to take the winner to update.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it helped. The .each function does an iteration which in this case isn't needed and honestly makes it harder. You can also use the existing class if you don't want to add an id. `$('.newsLetterDiv').eq(0).height()` will return the height of the first div for example.